# How to freeze windows 10 screen with Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a GUI program that notifies me if I sit too much in front of the PC, it tells me to drink water or take a walk based on the task and time given, but that can be ignored and closed easily if I click X, I want it to be restricting and serious. So is there any python code or cmd command that I can include in the program that is able to freeze the entire windows screen for a period of time?

EDITED:
If there's a way I can disable the mouse, would be great too.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Sheldon how would pausing a Python program pause everything else on the system? I don't think you've read this question.

Comment: @Random Davis: my bad, I will remove my comment.

Comment: You can call `os.system('shutdown -s -l -t 0')` to log off (or [sleep, shutdown, restart, etc.](https://superuser.com/a/463652)) but you can't easily disable the machine for a certain time without proprietary software.

Comment: Maybe you could use something like PyAutoGUI to repeatedly steal focus?

Comment: @RandomDavis That was great to consider, I set a fucntion like:                                     
 for i in range(50000):
        pyautogui.click(x=1024, y=768)         - Better than nothing, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a mixture `root.attributes()` and `root.protocol()`.

If you wanted a button to give you back control in your GUI, say after you had completed your tasks, you could use something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def foo():
    pass
root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True, "-topmost", True)
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", foo)

but = tk.Button(root, text = "I have completed my tasks", command=root.destroy)
but.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Or if you wanted a simple timer-activated screen that shuts off after a set time:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True, "-topmost", True, "-disabled", True)

time_interrupt = 5000 # Time screen is active in ms
root.after(time_interrupt, root.destroy)

root.mainloop()
```

Note these only work properly for a single screen, if you have multiple screens it may potentially work but you will likely need to add more code.

Comment: Great solution!! Thanks a lot!