# force selection of tkinter messagebox in touch screen

Tags: tkinter

messagebox.showerror() when using in multiroot touch screen it goes to background if user touch other parts of the screen. How can I force user to select OK

Comment: You cannot prevent user from touching other part of the screen when using `messagebox.showerror()`.  May be you can use a *fullscreen* and *topmost* window for showing the error like the solution of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70103764/how-to-freeze-windows-10-screen-with-python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can set main window uninteractable or invisible while popup window is active.

```
win.grab_set() # show popup window
win.grab_release() # return to normal
```

or

```
master.withdraw() # hide main window
master.deiconify()# return main window
```

Comment: Did you notice that OP is using `messagebox.showerror()`? So you cannot use something like `win.grab_set()` on the `showerror` dialog (I think it is called internally).  The main issue of OP case is that when user touchs *other part* of the screen, that is other application window, the `showerror` dialog is hidden by other application window.

Comment: @acw1668 you are correct about messagebox. My presented solution is not to use messagebox.showerror() and to use popup window. There was no code presented to this issue so unfortunately I went in different direction.